# Group Actions Question

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group with $|G| = 32$, which acts on some set $S$. Prove that if $|S|$ is odd, then there exists an element $s \in S$ such that $g(s) = s$ for all $g \in G$.

---

I was going to use $|S| = |G|/|H|$ but we do not know if the action is transitive. So I am not sure how to continue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the orbits of $G$ on $S$. They form a partition of $S$, hence the order of $S$ is the sum of the lengths of the distinct orbits. Now you know that the length of an orbit is the index of the stabilizer of an element in the orbit. If all stabilizers are proper subgroups, then all orbits have even length, while $S$ has odd order. Hence there is an element whose stabilizer is the whole of $G$.